# Защитить все файлы от прямого доступа

Tags: php

Пишу небольшую CMS, настройки и некоторые данные хранятся в XML файлах. Хотелось бы закрыть эти файлы от неавторизованных посетителей (авторизованному админу скрипты и так их достанут).

Пока решение такое: Создана директория site.ru\admin\storage c `deny from all` в .htaccess. Достаточно ли этого чтобы защитить данные от распространенных атак?

Хранить данные выше корня не получится(

Comment: Этого достаточно, если в движке нет других уязвимостей которые позволят выполнять на серерве произвольный код или path injection

Comment: Это поможет, если веб-сервер - Apache

Answer (score 1):

Если сервер Apache, то можно в .htaccess сделать так:

```
<Files ~ "\.xml$">
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_access_compat.c>
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        <IfModule !mod_access_compat.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule> 
</Files>
<Files sitemap.xml>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_access_compat.c>
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        <IfModule !mod_access_compat.c>
            Require all granted
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule> 
</Files>
```

Если Nginx, то можно в nginx.conf сделать так:

```
location ~* \.xml$ { deny all; }
location = /sitemap.xml { allow all; }
```

Comment: вот это location ~* \.xml$ { deny all; } в какую секцию воткнуть? не работает.