# Запретить доступ к файлам .log, .txt извне для всех сайтов

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

В корень сайтов складываются файлы .log, .txt. Не спрашивайте для чего)

Связка nginx-apache. Сейчас .htaccess каждого сайта настроен таким образом, чтобы пользователи сайта не имели доступ к этим файлам:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*.(log|txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Скажите, можно ли сразу для всех сайтов на уровне сервера/apache/nginx аналогично запретить доступ к файлам .log, .txt? и как это изящнее сделать?

Comment: Изящно это не складывать логи в папки доступные по сети.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Защитить все файлы от прямого доступа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500330/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0)